# EF CodeFirst and UserProfile in SimpleMembership

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a table Tale with definition

```
public class Tale
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    public int enum_TaleAuthorTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual enum_TaleAuthorType enum_TaleAuthorType { get; set; }

    public int CommentableId { get; set; }
    public virtual Commentable Commentable { get; set; }
}
```

and when i type 'update-database' in console, i have nice relationships with one column for CommentableId and one for enum_TaleAuthorTypeId.

Now, i'd like to add UserProfile and try to type something like:

```
    public int UserProfile_UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
```

but after add-migration, i have this:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.UserProfile",
            c => new
                {
                    UserId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    UserName = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserId);

        AddColumn("dbo.Tales", "UserProfile_UserId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("dbo.Tales", "UserProfile_UserId1", c => c.Int());
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Tales", "UserProfile_UserId1", "dbo.UserProfile", "UserId");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Tales", "UserProfile_UserId1");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.Tales", new[] { "UserProfile_UserId1" });
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Tales", "UserProfile_UserId1", "dbo.UserProfile");
        DropColumn("dbo.Tales", "UserProfile_UserId1");
        DropColumn("dbo.Tales", "UserProfile_UserId");
        DropTable("dbo.UserProfile");
    }
```

At first, looks like EF think to create table UserProfile (but it's already created and i dont need it). Then, EF want to add two columns 'UserProfile_UserId1' and 'UserProfile_UserId', but i really need one for value.

What's my problem?

Comment: Did you map the relationship with fluid syntax?

Comment: Dont know what's fluid syntax, but i have just built-in AccountModels and a few other classes, like Tale.

Comment: Well, if you're not going to use conventional mapping, then you need to explicitly map.  This is done with either attributes or fluent mapping.  The easiest way to solve this is to just delete the `UserProfile_UserId property.  But you also need to add a Tales navigation property to UserProfile.

Comment: But how i'll initialize then value of user, who added tale? I thought it should be in UserProfile_UserId property, in class Tale

Comment: I cant understand, why two previous tables added perfectly, and UserProfile not =\

Comment: Really?  Look at your two previous definitions careful.  Notice the difference?

Comment: Yeah, if i change to         public int UserProfileId { get; set; }
        public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; } it still will create two columns:             AddColumn("dbo.Tales", "UserProfileId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
            AddColumn("dbo.Tales", "UserProfile_UserId", c => c.Int());

Comment: Any help for my question or links?

Answer (score 0):

try to add in your context

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Ignore<UserProfile>();
    }
```